# Running an UPDATE ELSE INSERT command

Tags: mysql

I have a script running every minute that parses what's playing on the radio and `INSERTs` it into my table `music` which has the fields `band`, `song`, and `start_time`.

To prevent songs that are still playing on subsequent script executions, I set the following rule to prevent those songs from being readded:

```
ALTER TABLE music ADD UNIQUE unique_index (band, song, start_time);
```

Now, I'd like to change `start_time` to `last_played` and add `play_count`.

I was thinking of running an UPDATE to increment the play_count by 1 if the band and song exists in the table and the current last_played does not equal the current starting time. Then if that failed I'd INSERT a new record where where last_played equals the current starting time. That way, if the song already exists it gets updated, new songs can be added, and it prevents the same playing song from being added because of the unique_index.

```
Pseudo Code:
UPDATE music 
    SET play_count=play_count+1 
WHERE band = $band 
    AND song=$song 
    AND last_played!=$start_time 
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO music 
        (band, song, last_played, play_count) 
    VALUES 
        ($band, $song, $start_time, 1);
```

The problem is it looks like I can't run an UPDATE first then INSERT after command. Everything seems to be `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` command. If I run an INSERT first then UPDATE I'll have songs that are still playing fail on the INSERT (which is good), but since I can't have the `WHERE last_played!=$start_time` on the INSERT it'll will then increment my play_count when it runs the (which is bad).

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `last_played` *and* insert a new record for every `start_time`. Seems like you need two tables: one with `(band, song, last_played)` that has one row per band & song, and then one with `(band, song, start_time)` that has many rows per band & song, one row for each time it plays.

Comment: Your play_count column will be incremented every time this is called and the song is still playing. If called once per minute, and the song is 3 minutes long, each row will have 2 or 3 added in the ply count column. You're right, the correct syntax is the ```ON DUPLICATE KEY``` version. The order isn't the problem, it's your intended logic.

Comment: Edit your question and add your table schema.